# PHPmyadmin Stored Procedures Syntax Error if else

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

Stored Procedures syntax error at line 11 'BEGIN INSERT INTO customer(CUSTOMER_ID,NAME)'.............................................................................................................................................................................................................

[image: ERROR]

```sql
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS
        (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            country
        WHERE
            country_code = @country_code
    )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO customer(
        CUSTOMER_ID,
        NAME,
        EMAIL,
        COUNTRY_CODE,
        BUDGET,
        USED
    )
VALUES(
    @CUSTOMER_ID,
    @NAME,
    @EMAIL,
    @COUNTRY_CODE,
    @BUDGET,
    @USED
)
END ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO customer(
        CUSTOMER_ID,
        NAME,
        EMAIL,
        COUNTRY_CODE,
        BUDGET,
        USED
    )
VALUES(
    @CUSTOMER_ID,
    @NAME,
    @EMAIL,
    @COUNTRY_CODE,
    @BUDGET,
    @USED
)
END
END
```

Comment: Why is the code in your picture, that you did not copy in the code you have shown? (I am talking about the piece that start from `CREATE PROCEDURE.....`)

Comment: The error says "check the manual", the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html)  shows that every SQL-statement should end with a semi-colon(`;`)

Comment: That's not the correct syntax for if - see - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html ALSO you seem to be using the same name for parameters and columns -that's a no no..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `AddCustomer`(IN `CUSTOMER_ID` VARCHAR(4), IN `NAME` VARCHAR(50), IN `EMAIL` VARCHAR(50), IN `COUNTRY_CODE` VARCHAR(2), IN `COUNTRY_NAME` VARCHAR(50), IN `BUDGET` DECIMAL(18,2))
BEGIN
    IF  EXISTS
        (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            country
        WHERE
            country_code = country_code
    ) THEN
INSERT INTO customer(
    CUSTOMER_ID,
    NAME,
    EMAIL,
    COUNTRY_CODE,
    BUDGET,
    USED
)
VALUES(
    CUSTOMER_ID,
    NAME,
    EMAIL,
    COUNTRY_CODE,
    BUDGET,
    USED
) ; ELSE
INSERT INTO country(COUNTRY_CODE, COUNTRY_NAME)
VALUES(COUNTRY_CODE, COUNTRY_NAME) ;
INSERT INTO customer(
    CUSTOMER_ID,
    NAME,
    EMAIL,
    COUNTRY_CODE,
    BUDGET,
    USED
)
VALUES(
    CUSTOMER_ID,
    NAME,
    EMAIL,
    COUNTRY_CODE,
    BUDGET,
    USED
) ; 
END IF ;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```